# link change object in div

Tags: html, css, object, menu

I have the following html:

```
<div class="container">

    <header>
       <object type="text/html" data="nav_bar/navigation.html" style="width:1300px; height:70px;"></object>
    </header>

    <nav>
      <object type="text/html" data="side_menu/dates.html" style="width:300px; height:500px;"></object>
    </nav>

    <article>
      <object type="text/html" data="side_main/introduction.html" style="width:1002px; height:500px;"></object>
    </article>

</div>
```

the file dates.html in subfolder side_menu is a menu.
I want one of its button to change the object in the article element to
../side_main/main_side.html

Currently it loads the page in the nav div (_self) by default. I have changed the target to _top and _parent and keeps loading the page as _self

the layout of the page is done with CSS:

```
  div.container {
        width: 100%;
        border: 1px solid gray;
        background-color: white;
    }

    header, footer {
        padding: 0em;
        color: white;
        background-color: black;
        clear: left;
    }

    footer 
    {
        padding: 1em;
        text-align: center;}

    nav {
        float: left;
        max-width: 300px;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0em;
        overflow:hidden;
    }

    article {
        margin-left: 1px;
        border-left: none;
        padding: 0em;
        overflow:hidden;
    }
 </style>
```

I am not a programmer or web developer. I appreciate any solution, the simplest possible. Thanks

Comment: I think you're going to need to program this. What are you using? jQuery, Vanilla JS, or something else?

Comment: I could use JS but I am trying to keep it as simple as possible. it works fine with frames but everywhere it says that it is not a good idea to use them. I started looking at iframes but them I read that CSS is the way to go

Comment: You need to change the data attribute in your object.. CSS can't do this. I would suggest you make a plunk for this. If you build it, they will come.

Answer (score 0):

no sure if this is the best way but it works:
I added the other object within the same DIV and add an ID to each object

```
<article>
          <object type="text/html" id="intro" data="side_main/introduction.html" style="width:1002px; height:500px;"></object>
          <object type="text/html" id="dec7" data="side_main/main_side.html" style="width:1002px; height:500px;"></object>
</article>
```

on the button I added an onclick event that pass a number to a function

```
<a href="#" onclick="show_div(1)"><December 7</a>
```

the function changes the display of each DIV depending on the number passed to it

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function show_div(arg) {
          document.getElementById("intro").style.display = "none";
          document.getElementById("dec7").style.display = "none";
          if (arg == 1) {
            document.getElementById("dec7").style.display = "block";
          } else {
            document.getElementById("intro").style.display = "block";
          }
        }
</script>
```